# ckeditor custom context menu is not visible in read only mode

Tags: ckeditor

I created a custom context menu item with custom group as a plugin in ckeditor. The created menu item is visible in the editor during edit mode (readonly = false) but during read only mode the menu item is not visible.

Am I missing something as part of configuration?

Thanks in advance !